# Open Image in new activity on clicking a list view Item?

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

Here is my code i want to go to a new activity when i click on a list view item. It should open new activity with the picture downloaded in an AsyncTask.
I have done this so far.
But it gives a FC. Can anuy body help?

```
    public class     MainPage    extends ListActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.   layout.    contacts_list);

            final List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

            /** This block is for getting the image url to download from the server **/
            final GetDataFromDB getvalues = new GetDataFromDB();

            final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainPage.this,
                    "", "Gettting values from DB", true);
            new    Thread   (new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    String response = getvalues.getImageURLAndDesciptionFromDB();
                    System.out.println("Response : " + response);

                    dismissDialog(dialog);
                    if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {
                            dismissDialog(dialog);

                            // Got the response, now split it to get the image Urls and description
                            String all[] = response.split("##"); 
                            for(int k = 0; k < all.length; k++){
                                String urls_and_desc[] = all[k].split(","); //  urls_and_desc[0] contains image url and [1] -> description.
                                list.add(get(urls_and_desc[1],urls_and_desc[0]));
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        dismissDialog(dialog);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            /*************************** GOT data from Server ********************************************/

            ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(this, list);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
ListView lv = getListView();
//setContentView(lv);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this, ViewImage.class);
             //Get the value of the item you clicked
            Model model = list.get(position);
                 intent.putExtra("image", model.getURL());
            startActivity(intent);}
});
        }

        public void dismissDialog(final ProgressDialog dialog){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
        private Model get(String s, String url) {
            return new Model(s, url);
        }

    }
```

Here is my layout file "contact_list"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="0dp" >

  <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="00dp"
            android:dividerHeight="4dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:layout_margin="00dp"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:divider="#81F79F"

            android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

code for my new activity that will display the image by downloading it again from url without resizing it!

```
public class ViewImage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_image);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_image, menu);
        String country = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

        return true;

    }
```

edit: I was using the setContentView() twice! I have solved the problem now!  now the only problem is how can i pass the url from my PHP file to the new activity to download and show image with full resolution without resizing it!?

Edit: i have added this in MainPage.java for setonitemlistener();

```
 ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override 
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
            { 
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this, ViewImage.class);
                     Model model = list.get(position);
                     String myURL = model.getURL();

                     intent.putExtra("image", myURL);
                    startActivity(intent);}
        });
```

and in the new activity ViewImage.java

```
final String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(image);
        final AQuery aq=new AQuery(this);
        aq.id(R.id.imageView1).image(image, true, true, 200, 0);
```

now it works but only it downloads image in new activity(ViewImage.java) in first item of the listview.Though it downloads images on listview
Anybody Help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you pass the url of the image to your DownloadedImage Activity then refetch the image in your activity. Better use a ImageLoader like Nostra to use caching instead of loading it from url. It's only my suggestion. It's  your choice. Cheers!

Comment: I have a php file that contains urls cyz i'll add new images everyday in the app . Even im worried about memory usage vuz its going to load all the images! Thought if i resize them then the quality will be poor in the next activity that will open the fullscreen image! Idk how am i going to achieve this!

Comment: AFAIK. In terms of image quality, Nostra can handle that stuff. using ImageScaleType function of Nostra i think.

Comment: I'll be thankful to you if you can suggest me an example  or sample source for nostra!

Comment: alrighty then, this would be great. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try this now.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this, ViewImage.class);
             Model model = list.get(position);
             intent.putExtra("image", model.geturl());
            startActivity(intent);}
});
```

Comment: This is what i get on the logcat! 05-24 01:35:29.696: E/AndroidRuntime(891): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lazyloading/com.example.lazyloading.MainPage}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: for where you accessing listview

Comment: I have solved that problem. I was using the setContentView() twice in the program! though Thanks for the help mate.  Please check edit and see if you you can help me with passing the url from my php file and downloading the image in next activity

Comment: PLease see in my edit i have added code for new activity! i hav used it already. this is what i am doing in new activity.How can i download the image in that activity to display on imageview?

Comment: you can use aquery https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading library for download and show image

Comment: i have included aquery library but still it says aq cannot be resolved!

Comment: no i just downloaded it from the link u hav given! and pasted it in lib. What am i supposed to do ?

Comment: right click on your project -> go to properties -> go to java build path -> go to order and export -> then select library -> save

Comment: i did it but same result :(

Comment: clean the project or restart eclipse

Comment: aq.id( R . id. image1 ). image ("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/somepic.jpg"); i get the error aq cannot be resolved! Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: have you initialize it like,

Comment: AQuery aq = new AQuery(your activity context);

Comment: No!! ... Im using it in an activity. Shoyld i write AQuary aq=new AQuary;

Comment: use AQuery androidQuery = new AQuery(this);

Comment: the error disappeared but some pictures load and some doesnt load even if its loaded on the listview!

Comment: androidQuery.id(imageFullText).image(imageurl, true, true, 0, 0, new BitmapAjaxCallback() {
     @Override
     protected void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, AjaxStatus status) {
      super.callback(url, iv, bm, status);
      if (bm != null) {
       
       
      } else {
       
      }
     }
    });

Comment: try this and check if bitmap null then ni image at that url

Comment: actually it loads the image in first listview item's new activity!

Comment: then what is the problem

Comment: if i click on 2,3,4,...n item of listview it opens the new activity but does not load the image on it. i think something wrong in this snippet.. Model model = list.get(position);
             intent.putExtra("image", model.geturl());

Comment: yes you have to check model object at click on listitem

Comment: i dont understand where and how to implement this!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Clear How you get Image Url Fisrt If it Come From medel.getUrl() with respective postion of 
    list view accrding to erlier solution of regrading your problem Then on list view click 
    First get Url From model and put it into bundel like this as below menthion

    MainPage.java

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
        { 
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this, ViewImage.class);
             Model model = list.get(position);
             intent.putExtra("imageUrl", model.geturl());
             startActivity(intent);
       }
    });
ViewImage.java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.xmlview);
     new MyTask().execute();


}

Do background Method of MyTask
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
{
    try
    {
     String urlstr = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageUrl");
     URL url = new URL(urlstr);
     bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
     imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    } 
     catch(Exception e)
     {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
       return null;
}
```

Comment: i have tried this and i cant access url which i passed via putextra inside the asynctask..cant make static reference to a nonstatic variable!

Comment: My Task is method of ViewImage.java class method put it into this class and before call it get url which you pass from Mainpage.java on list item click listener and if you do not know how to get value from intent here it is example of String urlstr = getIntent().getExtras().getString("image_id");
     URL url = new URL(urlstr);